# Getting a 403 (Forbidden) while trying to use angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

Im trying to upload a RTF file using angular and I keep getting a 403 (Forbidden)error even though the directory exists. Im sure there is something that Im missing. Maybe its a security issue from the server side or its an issue with the code below. I know if I was to use this with php it would work but Im trying to stick to using angular.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $fileUpload){
    var file = $scope.mallData;
    $scope.notReady = true;
    $scope.upload = function() {
        $fileUpload.upload(file);
    };
 });

myApp.directive('fileUploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element) {

        $element.bind('change', function(e) {
                $scope.notReady = e.target.files.length == 0;
                $scope.files = [];
                for(i in e.target.files) {
                    if(typeof e.target.files[i] == 'object') $scope.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

myApp.service('$fileUpload', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.upload = function(files) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        for(i in files) {
            formData.append('file_'+i, files[i]);
        }
        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'mall/AB123456', data: formData, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, transformRequest: angular.identity})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    }
}]);
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Im not sure what to do here.

Comment: It's most likely a server side issue. Can you share the code for the 'mall/AB123456' endpoint on your server side?

Comment: I dont have anything in that folder. So maybe it will be best to stick to php for this?

Comment: You can't just post data to a folder from javascript and expect it to upload to the server. Even if you could, it would be a serious security concern, since that would mean that anyone could upload anything to your server. You need a backend to grab the post request from Angular, in order to verify the file and store it in the folder. PHP would do. You can still use Angular on the client side, you just need something to handle the upload once it's been sent by post request from Angular.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the issue. I just needed to make sure. Thank You